# How to deploy Java desktop Swing application on the cloud?

Tags: java, swing, jar, cloud

I've made a Swing .jar game which I want to run online. Is there any way in which I can make it run on the cloud, like on Azure? I made it into an applet, but its no fun. I know we can deploy Servlets on these clouds. How can I deploy this desktop application I made online?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO, Applet is the only solution, or may be Java Web Start.

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you need to deploy an application in the cloud it has to be a web based application.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use AJAXSWING to convert Java Desktop application(.jar) to Web Application(.war) automatically. Read the link [ajaxswing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/deploy_desktop_applications_to_cloud.html)