# Is it possible to deploy Java SE apps online?

Tags: java, swing

I found this question, but it's fairly old, so I don't know how much the world has changed:

[How to deploy Java desktop Swing application on the cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954017/how-to-deploy-java-desktop-swing-application-on-the-cloud)

I have a Swing app that I would like to distribute (a functional version, beyond putting the code in a repo), and I'm not sure what are my options. About Applets I only know the name, and I'm not sure what are the scopes of tools like Docker and Heroku.

Sorry if the question is too broad.

Comment: Honestly the best way (IMO) to distribute a Swing application would be to put it on GitHub. Or do you want to somehow protect who can see/download/use it?

Comment: Applets and [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) are being removed from JDK. What is your target java version?

Comment: Use a "installer" which the users can download

Comment: @ControlAltDel, I don't need to protect it at all, really. It's just a mini-game so I'm a bit more interested in sharing it with users than with fellow developers. I'll assume users mostly don't want to know anything about code, compiling, cloning repos, etc.

Comment: @Abra I have JDK 1.8u151 or so installed on my laptop and I developed it over it.

Comment: You can convert your Swing app to native Windows app using [Excelsior Jet compiler](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really deploy a Swing application "on the cloud". Swing is a desktop view technology. If you just need to make your application available for people to download and install on their own desktops, you can wrap it in an installer/launcher like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). When someone downloads and runs your installer .exe, it will extract your Swing application to their local file system.